# Is the explanatory variable in the generalized linear model viewed as a random variable or parameter?

Tags: generalized-linear-model

In the generalized linear model, the distribution of a random variable $Y$ is assumed to be an exponential family distribution, and it is written in terms of an explanatory variable $X$ and parameter $\theta$. I was wondering if $X$ is viewed as a parameter of the distribution of $Y$, or a random variable and the distribution of $Y$ mentioned earlier is in fact a conditional one given $X$?

If $X$ can be viewed as a random variable, there seems to me a problem here. In the generalized linear model, the distribution of a random variable $Y$ is assumed to be an exponential family distribution. But since the distribution of $Y$ depends on $X$, it is actually that $P(Y|X=x)$  is an exponential family distribution. $X$ can have any distribution, and the unconditional distribution of $Y$ may not be an exponential family distribution. So how shall we understand the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Neither. The x's are assumed known (fixed) as for regression. The mean of the Y's is written as a function ($g$) of the linear predictor, $X\beta$, but the $X$'s aren't parameters in that, they're constants.

Answer (score 3):

> If X can be viewed as a random variable, there seems to me a problem here. In the generalized linear model, the distribution of a random variable Y is assumed to be an exponential family distribution.

No, it's not.  The assumption holds for the conditional not the marginal distribution of Y.

> But since the distribution of Y depends on X, it is actually that P(Y|X=x) is an exponential family distribution.

Exactly.

> X can have any distribution, and the unconditional distribution of Y may not be an exponential family distribution. So how shall we understand the problem?

There is no problem.  (Which is fortunate, since if I remember correctly X and Y must be jointly Normal for all the marginal and conditional distributions to also be Normal, so marginal and conditional form matches will be quite rare).  In general, with arbitrary X, the marginal distribution won't be anything particularly familiar.

Perhaps a helpful way to think about motivating regression modelling is to consider the joint distribution P(X, Y) -- whatever that is -- and to note that whatever the distributional forms this can always be broken into P(X) and P(Y|X).  If you are willing to entertain the assumption that one set of parameters specifies P(X) and that another separate and unrelated set of parameters specifies P(Y | X), e.g. with some kind of causal model in the background, then it is reasonable to ignore P(X) and its parameters and work just with a (regression) model of the conditional distribution P(Y | X).

This approach can also be more efficient, since it is usually easier to learn a conditional model directly than to learn a joint model and then condition yourself.

Answer (score 2):

As in any regression model the response is modelled conditional on observed/set values of the predictors.

Comment: Thanks! So the distribution of response $Y$ may not be an exponential family distribution?

Comment: Unconditionally, if the predictors are random variables, it can be anything. Could be bimodal.

Comment: I saw in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model#Probability_distribution) and other books, they defined generalized linear model, by first claiming the distribution of response $Y$ has an exponential family distribution before introducing the explanatory variable $X$. That make me think the unconditional distribution of $Y$ is an exponential family distribution, although it may not be true.

Comment: It is not true. The conditional distribution is exponential family

Comment: A metacomment here is likely to seem trite but possibly worth underlining to @Tim. Wikipedia is very, very  patchy on many technical matters: sometimes utterly superb, sometimes dire. That's the nature of the beast.

Comment: I don't know why you'd think that. Suppose $Y=\beta_0 + \beta_1 X +\epsilon$, where $\epsilon\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, & $X$ is 0 or 100, with equal probability on either. [Fixed typo in previous comment]